# Received stock in trade for LLC units as part of an IPO. How to report paper gain?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, capital-gain, ipo

USA taxpayer.

An LLC in which I had units IPOed. I chose to have *some* of the units converted into stock instead of receiving cash. (Yeah, didn't expect tech implosion, but that doesn't matter for this.)

I understand that this is a taxable event just like the units that were converted into shares and sold for cash. But, on what form do I report this? (There is no tax to be *paid* as the units were held by a tax-exempt entity.)

Comment: What forms do you have to choose from? It generally is dependent on your country

Comment: USA, let me edit.

Comment: "I understand that this is a taxable event" - is it? Reorganization is generally not a taxable event.

Comment: For a C Corp, true. For an IPO of an LLC where the result is mass public ownership, apparently it is? (I can hassle the lawyer about it again.)